# Can I ask this in the EE parent site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is this a valid question for the EE exchange? “I’m an EE student who’s minoring in math and am curious about what upper division math classes will be beneficial to me in the industry and/or graduate school. If I go to graduate school I will most likely follow the controls path.”

Comment: It would be interesting and valuable, though perhaps not on-topic, to have a list of which kinds of math that is pre-requisites for working for a certain branch of EE. Assembled by professionals in that branch. Like - to work with digital logic, study set theory and boolean algebra. Etc. Because teachers and academics tend to tell you to study everything imaginable. I wish I had such a list when I was studying, because in my professional career, I haven't used half of the math I studied (and thus I have forgotten all about it by now). Time I could have spent studying something useful instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, career and class questions you want to ask about are not on topic on the main site. You could try the [EE.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) .